# Debug: crawled <200>... (referer: none)

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a spider for scraping a non-English website, inspired by the first spider bellow, but I cannot find out what is the difference between them that when I run the first code everything seems alright and I get the data, but running the second spider, I get this message: Crawled (200)....(referer: none)

The first spider:

```
import scrapy
import logging

class CountriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'countries'
    allowed_domains = ['www.worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries = response.xpath("//td/a")
        for country in countries:
            name = country.xpath(".//text()").get()
            link = country.xpath(".//@href").get()

            yield response.follow (url= link, callback=self.parse_country, meta={'country_name':name})
    def parse_country(self, response):
        name = response.request.meta['country_name']
        rows = response.xpath("(//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-list'])[1]/tbody/tr")
        for row in rows:
            year = row.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").get()
            population = row.xpath(".//td[2]/strong/text()").get()
            yield{
                'country_name' : name,
                'year' : year,
                'population' : population
            }
```

The second spider:

```
class xxxxxxxxSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'xxxxxxx'
allowed_domains = 
['www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87- 
 %D8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86']

start_urls =['https://www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87 
- 
 %D8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/']

def parse(self, response):
    specialties = response.xpath("//h3").getall()
    for specialty in specialties:
        name = specialty.xpath(".//text()").getall()
        link = specialty.xpath(".//@href").getall()
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_spacialty, meta = 
{'specialty_name':name})

def parse_spacialty(self, response):
    specialty_name = response.request.meta['specialty_name']
    specifications = response.xpath 
("/html/body/main/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div")
    for specification in specifications:
        doctor_name = specification.xpath(".//div[1]/a[2]/span/text()").get()
        doctor_specialty = specification.xpath 
(".//div[1]/a[2]/label/text()").get()
yield{
            'specialty_name':specialty_name,
            'doctor_name':doctor_name,
            'doctor_specialty':doctor_specialty,
}
```

The message I get after running the second spider:

```
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: roqaba)
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9
.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (d
efault, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (Op
enSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP
0
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.se
lectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'roqaba',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'roqaba.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['roqaba.spiders']}
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 8eab953821
87f480
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pag
es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-21 10:03:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-21 10:03:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.d
rsaina.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.d
rsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%A2%D9%86%
D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/> (referer: None)
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET ht
tps://www.drsaina.com/ConsultationDoctor/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87-%D
8%A2%D9%86%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\uti
ls\defer.py", line 117, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\uti
ls\python.py", line 345, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\uti
ls\python.py", line 345, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\referer.py", line 338, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spi
dermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\pc\anaconda3\envs\vitual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cor
e\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\pc\projects\roqaba\roqaba\spiders\darmankade.py", line 19, in p
arse
    name = specialty.xpath(".//text()").getall()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 533,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 44908,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.56041,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 5, 33, 49, 446308),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 5, 33, 47, 885898)}
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

By the way, I'm using scrapy 2.1 and python 3, if it matters.

Can someone help me out with the second code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three issues in your spider. The first one I notice is your `allowed_domains` field. You should make it less specific, else you probably won't be able to request another url. I think this should be enough:

```py
allowed_domains = ['www.drsaina.com']
```

The next issue is in your parse method. You are extracting all h3s with `getall()`, which returns a list of strings and then you try to extract from these strings using `xpath()`. Next issue is that you are calling `getall()` to extract name and link. I think what you want to call is either `get()` or `extract_first()`, which both return a single string.
Change it to the following and your error message should change.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    specialties = response.xpath("//h3")
    for specialty in specialties:
        name = specialty.xpath(".//text()").extract_first()
        link = specialty.xpath(".//@href").extract_first()
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_spacialty, meta={'specialty_name': name})
```

Comment: Hello @Patrick K. Thank you for your suggestion. The error when I did what you said changed from "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath' "
to "ValueError: URL can't be None". In both cases, the error related to "Crawled (200) <GET https://..../robots.txt> (referer: None)" stays the same. I don't know what are these errors about. When I get the .csv export, the file is created but it is empty.

Comment: @shimamasaeli Perfect! That means something with your xpath for the links is probably wrong. What I can see is that you are trying to extract an href from a h3 element. These don't have hrefs usually. You should probably search for an a tag on the page containing the link you need to follow.

Comment: Vowwwww!! I could never imagine this might be the reason in a thousand years!!! Thank you so much, haha:)))

Comment: @shimamasaeli Very happy that I could help :)